# How can I assign the link of image that I got with API to src of image?

Tags: javascript, html

I can't assign the link of image that I got with API to src of image. I'm using fetch to get info, (I'm new with APIs).

```js
    fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
        .then(respons => respons.json())
        .then(b => {
         let pic = b[0].flags.png;
         document.getElementById("img").src =  "pic";
        })
```

```html
<img src="" alt="" id="img">
```

Answer (score 1):

There’s a problem with your code. You created the variable named pic. But instead of assigning variable to src you are assigning `"pic"` string. The correct code is:

```
fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
        .then(respons => respons.json())
        .then(b => {
         let pic = b[0].flags.png;
         document.getElementById("img").src =  pic;
        })
```

Note that I removed quotes from `pic` variable.